# If $A: V \rightarrow V$ is a linaer map, then what's the definition of tr($A|_{u}$), $u$ unit vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional space and $A: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map that takes $w^\perp$ to $w^\perp$. Then prove that $tr(A|_{w^\perp}) = $ ...

I cannot even start without knowing what the definition of $tr(A|_{w^\perp})$ is.

Thank you in advance.

(This is John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifolds, 8-2)

Comment: Let $W$ be the vector space spanned by $w^\perp$. As $A$ takes $w^\perp$ to $w^\perp$, the map $B:W\rightarrow W, B(x)=A(x)$ is well-defined and you can use the usual definition of the trace.

Comment: In fact $B=id_W$ and so $tr(B)=...$?

Comment: @severin 1. (hopefully not $n$)

Comment: That is correct. What is your reasoning?

Comment: What is the dimension of $W$?

Comment: @Ted he said $W = span(w^\perp)$.

Comment: @James Ted Shifrin knows the answer very well. This was a hint for you to understand why the trace is equal to $1$ :)

Comment: Back up. $w$ is a single vector, I assume. I also assume you are writing $w^\perp$ to mean the orthogonal complement of the line spanned by $w$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh ok, that was an issue. dim $W = n-1$

Comment: Right, if I'm interpreting correctly.

Comment: Thank you, both of you.

Comment: Oh then it is me that misunderstood. I thought that by $w^\perp$ we mean a single vector. Otherwise we will also not be able to say anything about the trace (unless one interprets "taking $w^\perp$ to $w^\perp$" as "$w^\perp$ is fixed by $A$").